# I have this code to connect UDPClient In C#, Please Can Any one Tell me It is fine or not?

Tags: c#

Here Is My Code. 
I have written this code to Receive The Messages from the client in a Separated Thread. What I want to ask is, Is This fine as compared to using async callback methods.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start Receiving Messages from Clients
        remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4510);
        serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServerThreadMethod));
        serverThread.Start();
    }

    private void ServerThreadMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP); // listen on port 11000
            string rec_data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            this.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
                lblStatus.Text = rec_data + " -> receive data from " + remoteEP.ToString();
            }
            );
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean the code is fine. Will Timer make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this fine as compared to using async callback methods?

"Fine" according to what standard or point of view?

IMHO, network I/O should always be done with asynchronous methods. .NET offers a large number of viable options for doing so, and they are all more efficient than dedicating a single thread to each socket.

That said, other than the pointless call to `Thread.Sleep(1000);`, which you should remove, and the anomalous use of the `ThreadStart` delegate type instead of `MethodInvoker` (the latter is documented as being more efficient), the code you have looks "fine", from the point of view that it should work for small numbers of sockets and clients.